# How to use Gower's Distance with clustering algorithms in Python

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, pca, k-means, gower-similarity

I am trying to cluster by dataset with mixed features using k-means. As a distance metric, I am using Gower's Dissimilarity. I want to ask 2 things:

-Is k-means an appropriate algorithm that can accept Gower's matrix results as an input? or how can I use the output of Gower' matrix as an input of another clustering algorithm?

-Can I apply PCA or Kernel PCA on the results of Gower's Discance to decrease dimensionality so that I can visualize the results?

Answer (score 3):

K-means does *not* use a distance matrix.

The method requires a data matrix, because it computes the *mean*. It nowhere uses pairwise distances, but only "point to mean" distances. The mean is a good choice for *squared* Euclidean distance. It's not particularly good for regular Euclidean. It's only defined for continuous variables. So it cannot be used with Gower's on categoricial data.

If you have a distance matrix (and little enough data to store it), then hierarchical clustering is likely the method of choice.

Yes, it probably is a good idea to use non-metric multidimensional scaling (MDS) and tSNE to check if the distance function works on your data.  There is no guarantee that a distance gives useful results. If these visualization just give you a random-like blob, then do not expect the data to cluster with this distance.